# I couldn't find jar for oracle.wsm.common.config.WsmConfig

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, obiee

I couldn't find jar for

```
oracle.wsm.common.config.WsmConfig
```

I'm getting exception when running OBIEE webservice

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/wsm/common/config/WsmConfig
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationProcessor.populateConfigurationFromPapConfigFile(ConfigurationProcessor.java:536)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationProcessor.processConfiguration(ConfigurationProcessor.java:729)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationManager.resetAccessors(ConfigurationManager.java:1902)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationManager$2.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1862)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationManager$2.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1860)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationManager.reset(ConfigurationManager.java:1859)
    at oracle.wsm.config.ConfigurationManager.getRepositoryAccessor(ConfigurationManager.java:1512)
    at oracle.wsm.policyaccess.impl.PolicyAccessorImpl$1.run(PolicyAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at oracle.wsm.policyaccess.impl.PolicyAccessorImpl$1.run(PolicyAccessorImpl.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.wsm.policyaccess.impl.PolicyAccessorImpl.<init>(PolicyAccessorImpl.java:160)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.mgmt.PolicyCacheImpl.<init>(PolicyCacheImpl.java:354)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.mgmt.PolicyCacheImpl.getInstance(PolicyCacheImpl.java:81)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.getPolicySet(DispatchImpl.java:470)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.getPolicySet(DispatchImpl.java:457)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.OracleDispatchImpl.getPolicySet(OracleDispatchImpl.java:178)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.rm.util.RMUtils.getClientConfigurationInfo(RMUtils.java:144)
```

Anyone help me to find the jar file for above class?

Comment: that comes with Weblogic server installation https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/owsm/OWSMS/install-owsm-wls.htm#OWSMS3984

See in your weblogic installation and look for it under oracle/oracle_common/modules/

Comment: @Optional I looked at all the jar available under above mentioned folder. I did find this class in any of the jar

Comment: Is it a standalone WLS, or integrated WLS that comes with Jdeveloper? In standalone wls, you need the domain to have OWSM policy manager. If its not there, you need to extend your domain to include OWSM policy manager

Comment: @Optional  integrated WLS that comes with Jdeveloper.

Comment: @Optional can you tell me the jar file name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oracle/oracle_common/webservices/wsclient_extended.jar matches
oracle/oracle_common/modules/oracle.webservices_11.1.1/oracle.webservices.standalone.client.jar matches
oracle/oracle_common/modules/oracle.wsm.common_11.1.1/wsm-policy-core.jar matches

Are the jars I see containing the class, from wherever your jdev is installed. Which version of jdev you are using as the class is not required in newwer jdev i guess.

Comment: Thanks mate. You just saved my night ;)